# Deciding whether a binary matrix contains a permutation matrix

Tags: matrices, permutations, binary, decision-problems, permutation-matrices

I would like to know if there is any condition to check whether a binary matrix contains a permutation matrix of the same size. E.g.
$$A_1=\pmatrix{1&1&1&1\\ 1&0&0&1\\ 1&0&0&1\\ 1&0&0&0}$$
does not contain any permutation matrix, whereas 
$$A_2=\pmatrix{1&1&1&1\\ 1&0&1&1\\ 1&0&0&1\\ 1&0&0&0}$$
contains
$$P=\pmatrix{0&1&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0\\ 0&0&0&1\\ 1&0&0&0}.$$

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your use of 'decompose' is a bit unusual. Normally people use it as 'write as the sum of two other things' but here you mean, if I understand correctly, 'change some of the 1's into 0's'? Perhaps you could make that more explicit in the post.

Comment: I've tried to clarify your question. Please feel free to roll back or to make further edits when you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

A binary matrix contains a permutation matrix (in the sense illustrated by your example) if and only if its [permanent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent) is non-zero. The permanent can be [computed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computing_the_permanent) in $O(2^nn)$ time.

Comment: Note that this provides an upper bound for the complexity of the problem posed - it might be easier to show that the permanent is nonzero than to compute it.

Comment: perfect matching is in poly time